# I want attribute set name in sales order grid In that column I want an Ordered First Item Attribute Set Name. In Magento 2

Tags: magento2

```
<?php

namespace Emipro\AdminSalesOrderGrid\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Model\AttributeSetRepository;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;

class Attribute extends Column {

public function __construct(
    ContextInterface $context,
    OrderInterface $order,
    Item $item,
    CollectionFactory $collection,
    ProductFactory $product,
    AttributeSetRepository $attributeSet,
    UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
    array $components = [],
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->attributeSet = $attributeSet;
    $this->item = $item;
    $this->order = $order;
    $this->product = $product;
    $this->collection = $collection->create();
    parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
}

public function getAttributeSetIdByProductId($product_id) {
    $product = $this->product->create()->load($product_id);
    foreach ($product as $item) {
        $attribute_set_id = $product->getAttributeSetId();
        $attributeCollection = $this->attributeSet->get($attribute_set_id);
        foreach ($attributeCollection as $name) {
            $attribute_set_name = $name['attribute_set_name'];
        }
    }
    return $attribute_set_name;
}

public function getOrderDetails($entityId) {

    $orderCollection = $this->order->load($entityId);
    $ordered_items = $orderCollection->getAllItems();
    $item_sku = "";
    $attribute_set_name = "";
    foreach ($ordered_items as $item) {
        $item_id = $item->getItemId();
        $product_id = $item->getProductId();

        $attribute_set_name = $this->getAttributeSetIdByProductId($product_id);

        if ($item_id == 1) {
            $item_sku = $item->getSku();
        }

        return $attribute_set_name;
    }
}

public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource) {

    if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {

        foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as &$item) {

            $item[$this->getData('name')] = $this->getOrderDetails($item['entity_id']);

            // echo "<pre>";
            // print_r($item);
            // exit;
        }
    }
    return $dataSource;
}
}
```

Comment: Please explain in detail

Comment: I need a custom column in Sales Order Grid in Magento 2.3.0.

In that custom column i want to add "Orderd First Item"->attribute set name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php
namespace Emipro\AdminSalesOrderGrid\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
use \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;

class Attribute extends Column
{
    protected $_orderRepository;
    protected $_searchCriteria;

    protected $attributeSet;
    protected $_productloader;

    public function __construct(ContextInterface $context, UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory, OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository, SearchCriteriaBuilder $criteria, \Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeSetRepositoryInterface $attributeSet, \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_productloader, array $components = [], array $data = [])
    {
        $this->_orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->_searchCriteria  = $criteria;
        $this->attributeSet = $attributeSet;
        $this->_productloader = $_productloader;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    public function getAttributeSetName($product)
    {       
        $attributeSetRepository = $this->attributeSet->get($product->getAttributeSetId());
        return $attributeSetRepository->getAttributeSetName();
    }

    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {

                $order  = $this->_orderRepository->get($item["entity_id"]);
                $items = $order->getAllItems();
                foreach ($items as $_item) {
                    $productId = $_item->getProductId();
                    $product = $this->_productloader->create()->load($productId);
                    $attributeSetName =  $this->getAttributeSetName($product);
                    break;
                }
                $item[$this->getData('name')] = $attributeSetName;
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank for Replay. This is work for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace Emipro\AdminSalesOrderGrid\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Model\AttributeSetRepository;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
```

class Attribute extends Column {

```
public function __construct(
    ContextInterface $context,
    OrderInterface $order,
    Item $item,
    CollectionFactory $collection,
    ProductFactory $product,
    AttributeSetRepository $attributeSet,
    UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
    array $components = [],
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->attributeSet = $attributeSet;
    $this->item = $item;
    $this->order = $order;
    $this->product = $product;
    $this->collection = $collection->create();
    parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
}

public function getAttributeSetIdByProductId($product_id) {
    $product = $this->product->create()->load($product_id);
    foreach ($product as $item) {
        $attribute_set_id = $product->getAttributeSetId();
        $attributeCollection = $this->attributeSet->get($attribute_set_id);
        foreach ($attributeCollection as $name) {
            $attribute_set_name = $name['attribute_set_name'];
        }
    }
    return $attribute_set_name;
}

public function getOrderDetails($entityId) {

    $orderCollection = $this->order->load($entityId);
    $ordered_items = $orderCollection->getAllItems();
    $item_sku = "";
    $attribute_set_name = "";
    foreach ($ordered_items as $item) {
        $item_id = $item->getItemId();
        $product_id = $item->getProductId();

        $attribute_set_name = $this->getAttributeSetIdByProductId($product_id);

        if ($item_id == 1) {
            $item_sku = $item->getSku();
        }

        return $attribute_set_name;
    }
}

public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource) {

    if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {

        foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as &$item) {

            $item[$this->getData('name')] = $this->getOrderDetails($item['entity_id']);

        }
    }
    return $dataSource;
}
```

}